# gbrainy trains the brain true or false

Tags: games

i sometimes use [gbrainy](http://live.gnome.org/gbrainy) en was wondering does it really train the brain or not
cause there are a lot of [brain training software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_training) but after some reading.
 
i found out that they don't actually

my question is does Gbrainy really train your brain or not?

Comment: Everything you do 'trains' your brain, but this is too broad a question. The Wikipedia page you linked to states that this is 'virtually never used in the scientific literature'.

Comment: The question you have posted does not fall in the scope of questions discussed here. Please refer to the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions) to see what kind of questions you can ask here. Regards,

Answer (score 5):

That is kind of an odd and yet interesting question to ask:

The commonality of human brain-structure is more or less equal in its basic setup and follows certain patterns in an infinite number of variations, for different tasks and executions (to make a long story short), therefore i would say, it depends on "your" perceptional, epistemological sensation during and "after" playing gBrainy.

If you see change (only over longer periods of time) in your ability of logical thinking, memory increase (the ability of remembering) and an increased mathematical understanding, then you could use these as an indicator for success.

However so, i strongly doubt, that gBrainy (alone) is a source of success, since the human brain demands so much more to satisfy its need for improvement, at the same time it definitely does no harm either in that respect, apart from consuming your precious time, which could be used more efficiently on other tasks. (:

I suggest two things:

1. Try a few other programs (trial versions) as well, and see, if you like them:
   **Criterion:** GUI **|** Variety of user choices **|** level of difficulty etc..
2. The combination of different input sources mostly do the trick.
   For instance, your visual cortex highly differentiates between visual and audio-visual sources. The audio-visual effect causes your brain, not only to change the pattern, it also attempts the effort to combine different areas of the brain and increases neuro-electric stimulus, since the perceptual demand is higher to cope with the experienced information, but as said before, if you only keep your brain going with digital input, you'll neglect other important parts and pathways of it.

It is a good idea, to grab a good book once in a while, especially to train the memory and give the eyes a good rest from all the moving imagery. Remember, that in the past thousand years, humanity archived incredible cognitive ideas, art, solutions etc.. without computers.

Psychoactive Plants are also interesting in this regard (so i heard as a good citizen!)

I don't know about your interests, but good and interesting books like these "[The Art of Seeing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Seeing)", by Aldous Huxley, or "[The Hermetic Tradition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hermetic_Tradition)" by Giordano Bruno are quite recommendable, and so is history, psychology, philosophy etc..

Comment: I did not vote you down (actually i voted you +1 up to balance your votes), but as you see, sadly there is no room for off-topic questions here!!

Comment: Btw, one recent thing I closed from you is on the table at meta, care to have a look and drop some points? http://askubuntu.com/questions/115237/music-players-in-ubuntu-linux

Comment: Thank you Bruno Pereira! Ask me these kind of questions and i keep the both of us busy for some time (: What exactly do you have in mind?! The link leads back to my post, not to meta?! I got it: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2825/list-questions-fair-cases-of-knowledge-or-just-a-waste-of-time